# Authentication error (credentials missing in user document) in Mongo 3.0.1

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I am having trouble with a basic user connection to my new Mongo setup.

The error looks like this in mongo.log:

- authenticate db: a { authenticate: 1, user "u", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
- Failed to authenticate u@a with mechanism MONGODB-CR:AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in user document

and here is my user setup

```
> use a
switched to db a

> show users
{

"_id":"a.u",

"user":"u",

"db":"a",

roles:[

{

"role":"readWrite",

"db":"a"

},
{

"role":"dbAdmin",

"db":"a"

}
]
}
```

Id user u has readWrite on database a, why is he being rejected? All the examples I found when googling where users that were created in the wrong db.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to connect to MongoDB 3.0 with an older `mongo` shell or tool that is using the MONGO-CR authentication method. The default auth method for 3.0 is [SCRAM-SHA-1](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/). Check your shell version with `mongo --version` from the command line (or `version()` in a `mongo` shell session).